# How to use one datablock in 2 canvases?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a form where are there one window, multiple datablocks and multiple canvases.

I need to use one datablock called **USERS** on two different canvases **canvas1** and **canvas2**. But when I create the layout wizard the layout of the old canvas disappear and the form create the new one.

I want to use that datablock in canvas1 & canvas2.

Comment: the only way i can do this by creating two datablocks returns to the same tabel. its ugly that my form has two datablocks return to the same table.

Comment: Could you create a view on the table USERS that has the columns twice eg username1 and username2, then put username1 on canvas 1 and username2 on canvas2? You would need to ensure the ON-INSERT and ON-UPDATE triggers would update the appropriate columns on the table.

Comment: @TenG Thank you for your replay. this way was the same of create another datablock with same table and the name of it will be user1. I really want to use an offical way, or a professional way.

Comment: Only other way I can think is to have teh database column field as hidden, and have 2 items correspodning items one for each canvas that you tie to this column. This would require a lot of coding od WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM and PRE-DML triggers to ensure synchronisation and precedence rules. I cannot think of a cleaner way. The 2-block approach sounds the easiest.

Comment: "The 2-block approach sounds the easiest", its true. I dialed with this way right now. but I dont think oracle skip something like this.

Comment: You can do it, you just can't do it with the layout wizard.  You have to manually put fields on the second canvas.

Comment: @AndyDan I tried before to manually put fields in the second canvas but wont work. even when i duplicate the item on that block using Drag and drop wont work. if you have a way i kinldy asked you to show me. thanks

Comment: @AbdullahBahattab Once you have duplicated the field, you can update the canvas it displays on right in the field properties.

Comment: @AndyDan Thank you for your replay... I prefer repeating blocks over repeating fields for different properties in each block. I was hoping that there is a professional and official way to do this, but it seems that there is no other way than to duplicate blocks or fields .. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to build 2 `datablocks` with different names and direct each `datablock` to its own `canvas`. Also, in this way, you can also redirect each `datablock` to a tab in the same `canvas`. I don't think there is a way to make one `datablock` appear on 2 canvases. I had the same problem before and I couldn't find a solution other than this.

Comment: its has been so long time bro. anyway that is what I did. thank you